# MainWindow not subscribed to UserControl's event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I have some UserControls inside a MainWindow. I am trying to switch between my views by raising an event from UserControl and subscribing to that event in MainWindow.

I have seen answers to similar questions but none of them seem to help me.
I have tried the code below. While running code, `placeOrder` method in `MainWindowViewModel` is being hit, inside which I am raising `PlaceOrderRequested` event. And whenever this event is raised, `navigateToOrder` method in `MainWindowViewModel` should be called but that's not happening. Other commands in `MainWindowViewModel` are being called which are bound to some buttons. Please help me find the issue.

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public Command<Customer> PlaceOrderCommand { get; }  //uses placeOrder function
    public event Action<Customer> PlaceOrderRequested = delegate {};
    private void placeOrder(Customer cust)
    {//hitting here when put a breakpoint
        PlaceOrderRequested(cust);
    }
}
public class MainWindowViewModel: ViewModel
{
    public Command<string> NavCommand { get; }
    private OrderViewModel orderViewModel = new OrderViewModel();
    private CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        customerViewModel.PlaceOrderRequested += navigateToOrder;
    }
    private void navigateToOrder(Customer cust)
    {//not hitting here when put a breakpoint
    orderViewModel.Customer = cust;
    CurrentViewModel = orderViewModel;
    }
}
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
}
```

Here are my views, I have deleted unnecessary lines to keep the code minimal:

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_FirstAPP.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_FirstAPP"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MVVM_FirstAPP.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MVVM_FirstAPP.Views"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
            <views:CustomerView></views:CustomerView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OrderPrepViewModel}">
            <views:OrderPrepView></views:OrderPrepView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OrderViewModel}">
            <views:OrderView></views:OrderView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Customers"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Customer"/>
        <Button Content="OrderPrep"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="OrderPrep"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                        Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Customer View

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVM_FirstAPP.Views.CustomerView"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_FirstAPP.Views"
             xmlns:customerVM="clr-namespace:MVVM_FirstAPP.ViewModels">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <customerVM:CustomerViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                                    Binding="{Binding Id}"
                                    Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Width="*" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--On Click of this button I want to switch views. This button is calling PlaceOrder command which in turn is raising PlaceOrderRequested event-->
                            <Button Content="Place Order"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.PlaceOrderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am in Customer View and when clicking Place Order button, `placeOrder` is being hit where I am raising `PlaceOrderRequested` event. `MainWindowViewModel` has subscribed to this event but control is not going there.

Comment: I hit both breakpoints when trying your code. Can you provide a minimal working example which can build and reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AbdulAteek: How are you calling `placeOrder` in your example...?

Comment: I have updated code and mentioned how I am calling ```placeOrder```.

Comment: Consider an MVVM approach using an event aggregator, communicating between viewmodels instead. See `IEventAggregator` in [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).

Comment: @l33t I have just started learning about MVVM pattern and will sure consider exploring Prism. But, similar code is working in a Video tutorial and I couldn't figure why it is not working in this case.